# String based DateTime format or pattern check

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a datetime string.

```
string strDate = "20140424_18255375";
```

How to verify the datetime is having in this format `YYYYMMDD_HHmmssff`

I tried:

```
bool isTrue = DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, "YYYYMMDD_HHmmssff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

Please help if there is a better way to verify the datetimes with RegEx or any normal way.

Comment: RegExp might be difficult - e. g. how to handle leap years? So your solution should be good.

Comment: Good if you can help the format of DateTime to check with RegEx

Comment: Using Regex for this is like using srewdriver to plow the garden, it might work, but is it really the right tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `TryParseExact` is the right way to go about it, but you need to use the right [format specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In this case, I think you want:

```
bool valid =  DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, "yyyyMMdd_HHmmssff", 
                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

Note the use of `yyyy` instead of `YYYY` and `dd` instead of `DD`. Format specifiers are case-sensitive.

Comment: exactly what the OP had suggested

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    var dateString = value as string;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateString))
    {
        return true; // Not our problem
    }
    DateTime result;
    var success = DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out result);
    return success;
}
```

just add your format for date.